# How to POSTinput values from javascript function to another php page to save them into DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

this is my code to add dynamic rows on a table when click on the add button. Now i need to get the values entered into the text boxes and submit to DB.

```
<div id="addinput">
    <p>
    <button name="add" onclick="myFunction(this)" value="'.$btn_count.'"><font color="#FF0000" size="4">+</font></button>
    </p>
    </div>
    </td>
```

This is my functon to add dynamic rows to table, just below the row where we click

```
<script>
function myFunction(y)
{

var f = y.parentNode;
var d = f.parentNode;
var g = d.parentNode;
var c =g.parentNode.rowIndex;   


var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

var row = table.insertRow(c+1);


var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);

cell1.innerHTML = "<form name='frm_sub' id='frm_id' action='#'><input type=text  name='txt_id' id='id_id' size=10 placeholder=Id>";
cell2.innerHTML = "<input type=text name='txt_item' id='id_item' size=10 placeholder=Item>";
cell3.innerHTML = "<input type=text name='txt_cost' id='id_cost' size=10 placeholder=0.00>";
cell4.innerHTML = "<input type=text name='txt_wp' id='id_wp' size=10 placeholder=0.00>";
cell5.innerHTML = "<input type=text name='txt_rp' id='id_rp' size=10 placeholder=0.00>";

cell6.innerHTML = "<input type='button' name='submit' id='id_submitBtn' value='Save' size=10 onclick='form_submit()' ></form>";


document.getElementById("myTable");
```

}

```
function form_submit()
{


var item_name = $("input#id_item").val();

var cost = $("input#id_cost").val();

var wp = $("input#id_wp").val();

var rp = $("input#id_rp").val();

var dataString = 'item_name='+ item_name + '&cost=' + cost + '&wp=' + wp+ '&rp=' + rp;

alert(dataString);



$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url:newAdd.php,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {

            items : $("#id_item").val(),           
            cost : $("#id_cost").val(),
            wp : $("#id_wp").val(),
            rp : $("#id_rp").val(),
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("Success");
        }
    });



}
```

in newAdd.php i wrote

```
echo$itemName =$_POST["txt_item"];
$insert = mysql_query('INSERT INTO item (item) VALUES ('$itemName');
```

But this is not working..

Comment: I think this will work, quotes around.  url:'newAdd.php',

Answer (score 4):

```
if you are getting that alert  then this will work 


    function form_submit()
    {


    var item_name = $("input#id_item").val();

    var cost = $("input#id_cost").val();

    var wp = $("input#id_wp").val();

    var rp = $("input#id_rp").val();

    var dataString = 'item_name='+ item_name + '&cost=' + cost + '&wp=' + wp+ '&rp=' + rp;
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "newAdd.php",
        data:dataString,
        success: function(msg){ 
        alert('success');   

        }
        });



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ajax request. Hope this will help you -

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:'newAdd.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            items : $("#id_item").val(),           
            cost : $("#id_cost").val(),
            wp : $("#id_wp").val(),
            rp : $("#id_rp").val()
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("Success");
        }
    });
```